# I am facing strange issue to run react-native app on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9, react-native-ios

I just started working on react-native and setup all prerequisites as per instructions. 
But when I hit run then I am getting error. Here is the error

> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I am using Xcode 9 and react-native version 0.49.1

Comment: Try deleting `yourproject/ios/build` folder.

Comment: @MattyK14 Deleting build folder not working.

Comment: Does your info.plist have a Bundle Indentifier key & value?

Comment: Yes it has all required details. 

I have this entry


<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key><string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>

Answer (score 1):

You need to define in Xcode the bundle identifier something like "com.yourapp" clicking on the project target if I remember properly.